# Using Cypher to autogenerate IDs for SDN4

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have created a neo4j model with text file of `cypher` statements. Now i'd like to create an application that uses this database, and I'll be using SDN4. In my `@NodeEntity` class, I will need to have the `GraphID` of type `Long`declared. But this ID gets generated by SDN4, and my database doesn't have those IDs. Is there a way to have those created via Cypher so I can simply have my Java objects mapped correctly to the pre-existing nodes and relationships in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@GraphId` field is always the internal node or relationship ID assigned by Neo4j and cannot be set to custom values. You're probably looking to assign your own ID value as a property of the node.
This can be done by adding your own id field-

```
@GraphId Long graphId; //required, this is the internal node/rel ID that must never be assigned by your code
Long id; //your own primary key
```

Now, when your database contains nodes with a property `id` assigned by the statement in your Cypher script, loading the entities via SDN will populate these `id` fields in your domain object.

If you do not have your own primary keys but want an ID anyway, you can use a [UUID plugin](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) that will automatically assign UUID's to nodes when they're created via any means (SDN/Neo4j browser/API's etc.).

Comment: just to clarify, the `graphID` mentioned above is populated by SDN or neo4j? When I'm creating the node from Cypher, it gets an ID. Will this ID get mapped to the `graphID` automatically? In that case i don't need an additional UUID field - i just want my objects mapped correctly to preexisting nodes! I was under the impression that the GraphID has to be generated by SDN...

Comment: The graphId is generated by Neo4j. When you create a node via Cypher, Neo4j assigns this ID. When you load the node via SDN, then that ID is mapped to the graphId for you